# Is it possible to set two color inUILabel in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uilabel, uicolor

Currently i am working simple iPhone application, Using UILabel to display names like Delivered minu, i want to display two color like (Deliverd) as black and (minu) as a blue, Is it possible? please help me.

Advance in Thanks

I tried this but i can't fix this:

```
 deliveredLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Delivered"]; 
     deliveredLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
     nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Minu"];
     nameLabel.text.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
     label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",deliveredLabel.text,name.text];
```

Comment: https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/

Comment: Perhaps apple will fix this in an upcoming version of iOS?

Comment: @Minu I notice you have name.text in your label.text statement. Shouldn't it be nameLabel.text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a UIView & add 2 label in this one with text Delivered & another with Minu & set the color accordingly.

```
deliveredLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Delivered"]; 
    deliveredLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    deliveredLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Minu"];
    nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    nameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
```